# How i can show or Hide my block on the basis of data in my database

Tags: magento2

I am trying to make a slider in my product view page.. what I need to do is when an admin addon up-sell products from admin panel on front-end I have to check a condition that if a slider entry for upsells products exits in my database I have to run my custom .phtml file where I have made a slider, if a slider entry dose-not exits in database then I have to allow the core block of up-sell product
I have made a slider which is working very well I have strut to make a condition is explained above 
need help

i have created a file name as

> Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

here i have added a block

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Frontend\UpSells" name="product.info.upsell" template="Vendor_Module::slider.phtml" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare" name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
```

i want this block to run if data user has created a slider for upsell otherwise the core magento block for upsell should work

Comment: share some code you have done, like how did you call custom .phtml on left bar

Comment: check updated answer now

Answer (score 0):

if you call your custom phtml with `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` then you can access your current product by `$_product = $block->getProduct();` so change your xml with this:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.upsell" template="Vendor_Module::slider.phtml" >
    <arguments>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
    </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare" name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
    </block>
</block>
```

and in your phtml you can add this check

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
if(count($_product->getUpSellProductIds()) > 0){
    //YOUR CODE HERE
}
```